# Access to external value inside apply

Tags: kotlin

*Short example:*

```
class MyClass {
 val someName = "want this value"
 val someOther = SomeOther().apply{ someName = someName }
 // other stuff below
}
```

`SomeOther` will apply the value of its own `someName` to `someName`, so value application makes no difference (x=x).

**Q:** How can I access external `someName` (*"want this value"*) being inside `apply`?

**UPDATE**
I have further doubts related to suggestion to use `this.someName=someName`, below 2 code snippets, the first one works as expected, surprisingly the second fails with similar behavior as described.

*First*

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    class SomeOther {
        var someName: String? = null
    }
    val someName = "want this value"
    print(SomeOther().apply { this.someName = someName }.someName) // works!

}
```

*Second*

```
class SomeOther {
    var someName: String? = null
}

class MyClass {
    val someName = "want this value"
    val someOther = SomeOther().apply { this.someName = someName }
    fun go() = print(someOther.someName)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) = MyClass().go() // prints null
```

**Q:** Where's the difference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the `also`-function instead. It is equivalent to `apply`, except it will bind your object to `it` instead of `this`:

```
val someName = "want this value"
val someOther = SomeOther().also { it.someName = someName }
```

The `also`-function was added to Kotlin 1.1 specifially for when you do not want to shadow `this` from the outer scope.

Answer (score 10):

using [this reference expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html) as below:

```
val someOther = SomeOther().apply { someName = this@MyClass.someName }
//                 reference to the outer class ---^
```

**AND** the `T.apply` function is a convenient way to applying [Builder Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), in this way you never need using `this` or additional parameter at all, for example:

```
val foo = Foo().apply {
  //v--- no need using `this` or any addition parameters
    foo = "bar"
    fuzz = "buzz"
}

class Foo {
    lateinit var foo: String;
    lateinit var fuzz: String
}
```

### Edit

you can assuming `apply(lambda)` which will apply an anonymous class of `Function2<T,ARG,T>` instance, then you know why immediately?

in your first approach it looks like as below:

```
val lambda: Function2<SomeOther, String, SomeOther> = { thisRef, arg ->
    thisRef.someName = arg;
    //                 ^--- parameter is used in lambda
    thisRef
}

val someName = lambda(SomeOther(), "want this value").someName

println(someName)
```

in your second approach it looks like as below:

```
class MyClass {
    val lambda: Function2<SomeOther, MyClass, SomeOther> = { thisRef, arg ->
        //              the parameter `arg` is never used in lambda ---^
        thisRef.someName = thisRef.someName
        //                    ^--- it use thisRef's someName rather than arg's
        thisRef
    }

    val someOther = lambda(SomeOther(), this)
}
```

Comment: Also works but it's slightly more complex comparing to `also`, anyway, appreciate your help.

Comment: @wilu hi, the `apply` function is a convenient way to build the objects. you can omit `this` at left side, maybe it is not not present in your question. please see my edited answer again.

Comment: @wilu could you understand it now?

Comment: Yeah, I think I catch on intuitively but still I need to review deeper your examples. Thanks!

Comment: @wilu Not at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can access out of apply like that

```
class SomeOther {
    var someName: String? = null
}

class MyClass {
    val someName = "want this value"
    val someOther = SomeOther().apply { this.someName = this@SomeOther.someName }
    fun go() = print(someOther.someName)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
val someName = "want this value"
val otherName = SomeOther().apply { this.someName = someName }
//                     internal someName ---^          ^
//                                external someName ---^

print(otherName.someName) // >>> want this name
```

Comment: This is a wrong answer. they both refer to same instance.